# Can Functional Interfaces with generic type be stored in a static map?

Tags: java, generics, static, functional-interface

I have used a static map to store a series of Functional Interfaces which associated with three classes A, B and C all inherited from a parent class. The code runs smoothly as follow:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    maps.put(A.class, BiConsumerA);
    maps.put(B.class, BiConsumerB);
    maps.put(C.class, BiConsumerC);
}

private static BiConsumer<A, String> BiComsumerA = (a, string) -> {//do something}
private static BiConsumer<B, String> BiComsumerB = (b, string) -> {//do something}
private static BiConsumer<C, String> BiComsumerC = (c, string) -> {//do something}

public static<T extends Parent> void exec(T t, String string) {
    maps.get(t.getClass()).accept(t, map);
}
```

However, there is a warning "Raw use of parameterized class 'BiConsumer'" on the usage of Biconsumer in the static map. I tried various ways to add a parameterized type to 'BiConsumer' but unsuccessfully. Such as:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<?, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<? extends Parent, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<T, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<T extends Parent, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
```

So my question is: Can Functional Interfaces with generic type be stored in a static map? If the answer is no, using Functional Interfaces directly, is it the only way to use Functional Interfaces in a static map? Are there more proper implementations? Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: `private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<?, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();` looks like it should have compiled without warning. But can you explain more why you need this? Note this this kind of map lookup won't work with subclasses, if you put `Number.class` into your map, it won't match `Integer.ONE.getClass()`.

Comment: Notice that your code is not type safe - There is no guarantee that `maps.get(A.class)` stores a `BiConsumer<A, String>`. It could just as well store a `BiConsumer<B, String>`. There is no way to say "the biconsumer's first parameter type must match its corresponding key's class", so it is completely justified that you can't put all your consumers into a single map.

Comment: @Thilo Thank you for help. Using a wildcard may cause error message `Required type: capture of ? Provided: T` in the code `maps.get(t.getClass()).accept(t, maps);`

Comment: Yes, as @Sweeper points out, you will have to have an unsafe cast in here. The compiler will not know that this BiConsumer is related to T.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your notice. How about use reflection to obtain the class type from the BiConsumer's parameter? Like this `maps.put(getType(BiConsumerA), BiConsumerA);` and `getType implements e.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()[0].getGenericParameterTypes()[0];` Is this a proper implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can Functional Interfaces with generic type be stored in a static map?

Yes, of course. List is easier for sake of demonstration:

```
private static List<Consumer<?>> listOfConsumers = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init2() {
    Consumer<String> stringConsumer = str -> System.out.println(str);
    Consumer<Integer> intConsumer = i -> System.out.println(i);
        
    listOfConsumers.add(stringConsumer);
    listOfConsumers.add(intConsumer);
}
```

> However, there is a warning "Raw use of parameterized class 'BiConsumer'"

Just use a wildcard instead of a particular parameter.

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<?, String>> maps = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
```

Comment: Notice that OP also calls the biconsumers in this way: `maps.get(t.getClass()).accept(t, maps);`.

Comment: Thank you for help. Using a wildcard may cause error message `Required type:
capture of ? Provided: T` in the code `maps.get(t.getClass()).accept(t, maps);`

Comment: Yes, you will have to have an unsafe cast in here. The compiler will not know that this BiConsumer is related to `T`.